# kubernetes-Ingress resource is not working as expected to expose 2 apps using subdomains

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, apache-karaf, kubernetes-pod, nginx-ingress

I want to have 2 apps running on kubernetes using a ingress resource to point to each app in the same port.

I should be able to access app1 version in `app1.localhost:8181/cxf`, and app2 version in `app2.localhost:8181/cxf`

Im using docker with kubernetes, mysql and karaf with a kar. I'm testing locally (localhost).

I tried a lot of things that I searched on the internet, including adding to the hosts the ip + hostname, but no luck. What happens is that it always shows the same app, doesn't matter the hostname I insert.

before sharing my yamls, I have some questions:

1:
I was thinking that maybe I should have 2 nodes? one with mysql and app1 and the other one with mysql and app2? so in one I could access `app1.localhost/cxf` services and in the other `app2.localhost/cxf` services... maybe doesn't make much sense... and I was reading that I need kubeadm for that, and there is no way to install it on windows. I think I must use minikube for that instead?

2:
shouldn't I be able to create another loadBalancer? I wanted to, so the selector would be app2 in that loadBalancer, but since I already have one, the new one just stays `<pending>` until I remove the first one.
But when I installed the nginx-ingress controller it came with a type loadBalancer, and if I create an yaml with the same content, changing the ports it will work and wont stay pending...why?

3:
if I have 2 replicas of app1, and 2 replicas of app2, there should be a loadBalancer for each app right?

4:
Should I include a loadBalancer for mysql? does it make sense having mysql replicas?

5:
Since when I install nginx-controller, when I check my kubernetes dashboard there is a loadBalancer that came with it. Its ok to edit and add my karaf ports to expose the service?

Note that I installed the nginx ingress-controller using helm, since the ingress-resource would not work otherwise, at least thats what I have read. I used helm for that: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md#using-helm

Note:mysql is working fine so Im not posting the yaml's here so it doesn't get too long.

These are my yaml's:

**The load balancer:** (That I can replace for nginx load balancer?)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lb-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: app1
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: app1
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
  - protocol: TCP
    name: app1-8080
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  - protocol: TCP
    name: app1-8101
    port: 8101
    targetPort: 8101
  - protocol: TCP
    name: app1-8181
    port: 8181
    targetPort: 8181
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - hostname: localhost
```

**app1:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8101
  selector:
    app: app1
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: app1:latest
```

**app2:** is the same as app1 but in a diferent version(older services)

**ingress-resource:** (this is nor working)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apps-ingress
  #annotations:
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-service
          servicePort: 8181
  - host: app2.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app2-service
          servicePort: 8181
```

Huum, im missing something here...

Thanks for your time!

edit:

I guess I found the problem, and im now trying to resolve it.
Seems like ingress works in port 80 only for http, and im using cxf to list my services under port 8181. and 8080 for soap services.
so I guess I have to expose those ports and I will be fine? gonna try it

edit 2: I tried but it's not working, I followed this example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

The example works fine, but when I change the ingress to work with my app it doesn't work.
I need to access the :8181/cxf for my app to work, is there any way to do that?
Since ingress uses port 80, when I put `app1.localhost`, its the same as `app1.localhost:80` right?. the thing is, I need to `app1.localhost:8181/cxf` for me to access my services. but I guess that will be translated to: `app1.localhost:80:8181/cxf` ??

Can some one help? :(
When I say port 8181, I guess I can use another one using `nodePort:` that's basically the port forward right? but the problem if I do that, when I want to deploy my second app to access in `app2.localhost` if I put the same `nodePort` it will end in error since I want the port to be the same, but diferent hostname.

Comment: Is the port 8181 mandatory? Did I assume correctly that you want to expose `HTTP/HTTPS` traffic and currently you are using `minikube`? If you want to expose `HTTP/HTTPS` traffic that has subdomains you should use `Ingress` resource like yours and services of type `ClusterIP` or `NodePort`. Here you have a tutorial for ingress in minikube (you will need to modify ingress resource used there): https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Comment: @DawidKruk 

I was trying the port 8181 since it was there that all my services were, and it was the port I was using before coming to the kubernetes world.
It should work with 8181 but I guess I can use another one.

I wasn't using minikube, I was using docker + kubernetes, but since I wasn't able to do it, Im now trying minikube, The thing I dont like, is that now, since I turned off docker kubernetes(or can it still be on?) I can't see the containers on docker dashboard :(

Im using now NodePort, Im configuring now the ingress, gonna give feedback after. thanks

Comment: Well, it didn't work.
Without ingress, I can access the apps with diferent ports.
But Im trying to use ingress so I can just use diferent hostnames as said in the mais post... Using nodePort to define the port to access the app ex 30001 for app1, but I cant use the same for the app2. I can use the same servicePort in the ingress config, but wtv I put doesn't seem to work.
I did put the ip + hostname in etc/hosts

its like ingress is not working at all. 
I want to access app 1 in for ex: v1.app:8181/cxf
and app2 in v2.app:8181/cxf . the port can be 30001 or wtv. but should be the same.

Comment: I understand the problem now, gonna edit the main post to explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering questions in the post:

> 1: I was thinking that maybe I should have 2 nodes? one with mysql and app1 and the other one with mysql and app2? so in one I could access app1.localhost/cxf services and in the other app2.localhost/cxf services... maybe doesn't make much sense... and I was reading that I need kubeadm for that, and there is no way to install it on windows. I think I must use minikube for that instead?

You don't need to have 2 nodes. You can use single node Kubernetes installation for example `minikube` or Docker Desktop (with Kubernetes) to spawn your `app1`, `app2` and your `mysql`. I will include the guide to expose example apps like you mentioned on the end of this answer.

As for `kubeadm`:

> kubeadm performs the actions necessary to get a minimum viable cluster up and running. By design, it cares only about bootstrapping, not about provisioning machines.
>
> *[Kubernetes.io: kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/)*

In simple words `kubeadm` is used on machines (bare-metal, VM's) to run the steps to provision the Kubernetes cluster (assuming that OS is installed, configured etc.)

> A tip!
>
> `minikube` is using `kubeadm` to provision it's single node cluster.

---

> 2: shouldn't I be able to create another loadBalancer? I wanted to, so the selector would be app2 in that loadBalancer, but since I already have one, the new one just stays  until I remove the first one. But when I installed the nginx-ingress controller it came with a type loadBalancer, and if I create an yaml with the same content, changing the ports it will work and wont stay pending...why?

We will need to distinguish 2 terms here:

- service of type `LoadBalancer` - is used to expose your apps externally using a cloud provider's load balancer. In solution like `minikube` or `docker` it's usually mapped to the VM's IP (`minikube`) or localhost your machine (Docker)
- `Ingress` resource - exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.

In my experience service of type `LoadBalancer` is mostly using `Layer4` where `Ingress` resource is operating at `Layer7`. `LoadBalancer` won't route your traffic based on the `Host` header. It will route based on the labels and selectors of your service and your `Deployment`. `Ingress` resource is designed to serve `HTTP`/`HTTPS` traffic. It will incorporate tools that will route your traffic based on the `Host` header.

This are 2 separate ways to expose your apps and should be treated as different.

> **A tip!**
>
> `nginx-ingress` is using service of type `LoadBalancer` to route the traffic to  `nginx-ingress-controller`. From there it's analyzed and sent to the specific destinations (according to `Ingress` resource)!

The fact that you have `Pending` in the `External-IP` column could be related to the fact that the ports used in the service of type `LoadBalancer` are already used (`port` parameter).

---

> 3: if I have 2 replicas of app1, and 2 replicas of app2, there should be a loadBalancer for each app right?

For each app you need to have a `LoadBalancer`. It doesn't matter how many replicas your app has (it can be even 100). Basing on previous sentence:

- `app1` - 1st service of type `LoadBalancer`
- `app2` - 2nd service of type `LoadBalancer`

I try to think like below when exposing apps (it's really simplified):

- I'm exposing traffic which **is not** `HTTP`/`HTTPS` - service of type `LoadBalancer`
- I'm exposing some example app/apps and I need to have functionalities of `Ingress` (`Host` based routing, rewrites, SSL, etc.) - `Ingress` resource

> Disclaimer!
>
> You don't need to use service of type `LoadBalancer` when exposing apps with `Ingress` resource.

---

> 4: Should I include a loadBalancer for mysql? does it make sense having mysql replicas?

There are a lot of useful guides on deploying mysql in Kubernetes. To give your `app1` and `app2` an access to your `mysql` pod you can use service of type `ClusterIP` or a `headlessService`. The multiple replicas of your `mysql` will definitely increase fault tolerance in multi node clusters but it would need to have some kind of replication logic already included.

You can read more by following below links:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Defining a service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Headless services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Run replicated stateful application](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/)*

---

> 5: Since when I install nginx-controller, when I check my kubernetes dashboard there is a loadBalancer that came with it. Its ok to edit and add my karaf ports to expose the service?

Service of type `LoadBalancer` that was created when provisioning `ingress-nginx-controller` was specifically created only for `ingress-nginx-controller`.

If you would like to expose your `karaf` you have an option to:

- Expose it with `ingress-nginx-controller` according to the specification of your `Ingress` resource.
- Expose it with `nginx-ingress-controller` via [TCP/UDP services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/) (it will not have the features of `Ingress` resource):
- Expose it with another example of service of type `LoadBalancer`

---

---

**This guide is designed to work with `Docker Desktop` with Kubernetes installed**.

Assuming that you want to:

> I should be able to access app1 version in app1.localhost:8181/cxf, and app2 version in app2.localhost:8181/cxf

Assuming that you have a working Kubernetes instance with your Docker Desktop you will need to follow below example:

- Install `nginx-ingress`
- Spawn `hello-one` example app and a service associated with it
- Spawn `hello-two` example app and a service associated with it
- Edit the `nginx-ingress` service of type `LoadBalancer`
- Create and apply an `Ingress` resource
- Make some DNS changes
- Test

---

#### Install `nginx-ingress`

Run:

`$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.35.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

> Disclaimer!
>
> 1. There could be differences when trying to follow this steps between Windows and Mac based environments
> 2. There could be differences when trying to follow this steps on `minikube` instances

Installation page:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress-nginx: Deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)*

---

#### Spawn `hello-one` example app and a service associated with it

Here is the definition for `hello-one` app:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-one
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-one
      version: 1.0.0
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-one
        version: 1.0.0
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0" # <-- notice the 1.0
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"
```

Here is the definition for a service for `hello-one` app:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-one-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello-one
    version: 1.0.0
  ports:
  - name: hello-one-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 50001
```

---

#### Spawn `hello-two` example app and a service associated with it

Here is the definition for `hello-two` app:

```yaml
apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-two
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-two
      version: 2.0.0
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-two
        version: 2.0.0
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0" # <-- notice the 2.0
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"
```

Here is the definition for a service for `hello-two` app:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-two-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello-two
    version: 2.0.0
  ports:
  - name: hello-two-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 50001
```

---

#### Edit the `nginx-ingress` service of type `LoadBalancer`

You will need to edit the service of type `LoadBalancer` of your `nginx-ingress-controller` to support ports other than `80` and `443`.

- `$ kubectl edit service -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller`

The part responsible for routing:

```yaml
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 32202
    port: 80 # <-- CHANGE HERE FOR 8181!
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    nodePort: 31130
    port: 443 # <-- CHANGE HERE FOR 8182!
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
```

---

#### Create and apply an `Ingress` resource

You will need to use the following `Ingress` resource to have an access to your apps on:

- `hello-one.kubernetes.local:8181/cxf`
- `hello-two.kubernetes.lcoal:8181/cxf`

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress 
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-one.kubernetes.docker.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-one-service 
          servicePort: hello-one-port
  - host: hello-two.kubernetes.docker.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-two-service 
          servicePort: hello-two-port
```

> Disclaimer!
>
> This `Ingress` doesn't have the `/cxf` path configured. You can look here for more resources:
>
> - *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress path matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/)*

---

#### Make some DNS changes

You will need to edit the DNS setting of your host to support newly created `host` names. This part will depend on the OS you use. Lines to add:

```sh
127.0.0.1 hello-one.kubernetes.docker.internal
127.0.0.1 hello-two.kubernetes.docker.internal
```

---

#### Test

You can test your setup by either `curl` or your web browser:

- `$ curl hello-one.kubernetes.docker.internal:8181`

```sh
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: hello-one-696db54c4d-5fqt8
```

- `$ curl hello-two.kubernetes.docker.internal:8181`

```sh
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: hello-two-664ddf4cf6-4jhfr
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the long answer! It really helped me a lot to understand better what's going on.

I followed your post, And did exactly what you told me, but even so, my ingress didn't work, I always get `502 Bad Gateway` I checked a lot of times, and everything seems ok. I checked the link for the path configuration too, but no luck.

I have two questions regarding your post:
1-what is the `env name value` you have in deployment?
2-you defined port 80 on the service, then you give that port by name in the resource, and then edit the controlled for the routing. correct?

Comment: After saying that, yesterday night I did managed do make it work as I wanted.
I didnt do much tests, but here what I did: I was using minikube, what I did was create a service LoadBalancer for each deployment `kubectl expose deployment app1  --port=8181 --target-port=8181 --name=app1 --type=LoadBalancer`

then, the load balancer had an external ip, where I added in the hosts with v1.app for example. I did that to both apps. and in the end I could access app1 in v1.app:8181/cxf and v2.app:8181/cxf its seems to work fine. but is that a good idea to do? im new into kubernetes so...im worried.

Comment: oh, I forgot to say, after exposing using LoadBalancer, I had to do minikube tunnel.
and btw, I still had the ingress resource installed, but I guess it wasn't doing nothing, since I ended up using load balancer.

It is still hard to me to understand the diference of load balancer and ingress lol...
as I said, I didnt do more tests, and after seeing your answer, I was trying using the ingress again. hope you can clarify me, if its ok for me  to do it this way, or not.
thanks a lot

Comment: Answering first comment: `env` is just used for a variable to tell the app in the deployment to serve the content on some port (in this case `50001`). The link I posted with `nginx-ingress` is spawning everything (`Deployment`, `Service`, etc...). I edited the service associated with `nginx-ingress-controller`. To check for potential 502 errors run: `$ kubectl describe ingress`, `$ kubectl get endpoints`. I created this example specifically for Docker Desktop as you used it first. `Minikube` will behave differently when trying to expose traffic outside (implementation and `--driver` used).

Comment: Here you have some more explanation on services side of things: https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0 . Let me know if there's still something unclear.

Comment: Thanks again for the fast answer!

Thats everything I needed!
you helped me a lot! thanks!

Comment: I managed to put the ingress working, I had to give port 8181 in the targetPort.
My services are on 8181(rest) and 8080(soap).
I tried to add that port in the nginx load balancer, but didnt work, not sure if possible, but well, im gonna use the loadbalancer service as I said before. I wont even need to edit and add ports, since it will go in the yaml.

Comment: in docker kubernetes, when defining a load balancer, it always give localhost as external endpoint...

Comment: This is by far the most complete sample out there on the internet I found ! In my case, I had to add those lines in ingress to make it works :
...
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
...